# Why do my changes to model instances not get saved sometimes in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model named Post and I created two methods within the model that make changes to fields. The first method's changes get persisted when a save is called. The second method's changes do not get saved. I have noticed this behavior before in other models and I think I'm missing some basic knowledge on how models work. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  def publish(user) # These changes get saved
    reviewed_by = user
    touch(:reviewed_at)    
    active = true    
  end  

  def unpublish() # These changes get ignored.
    reviewed_by = nil
    reviewed_at = nil
    active = false
  end 

end
```

**EDIT:**

Here is a snippet from the controller"

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def publish
    if request.post? 
      post = Post.find(params[:id].to_i)     
      post.publish(current_user)       
      redirect_to(post, :notice => 'Post was successfully published.')
    end     
  end

  def unpublish
    if request.post? 
      post = Post.find(params[:id].to_i)     
      post.unpublish() 
      redirect_to(post, :notice => 'Post was successfully unpublished.')
    end     
  end

  ...
```

**UPDATE** 
Problem was solved by adding self to all the attributes being changed in the model. Thanks [Simone Carletti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123527/simone-carletti)

Comment: can you show your callbacks
:before_save etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `publish` you call the method [touch](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-touch) that saves the changes to the database. In `unpublish`, you don't save anything to the database.

If you want to update a model, be sure to use a method that saves the changes to the database.

```
def publish(user)
  self.reviewed_by = user
  self.active = true
  self.reviewed_at = Time.now
  save!
end

def unpublish
  self.reviewed_by = nil
  self.reviewed_at = nil
  self.active = false
  save!
end
```

Also, make sure to use self.attribute when you set a value, otherwise the attribute will be consideres as a local variable.

Comment: It is definitely the missing "self.". +1 for being right on both counts.

Comment: selflessness!! So is better to save in my model's methods? or in the controller?

Comment: It depends on the usage. In your case, since the controller doesn't need to do anything else on the object and the methods can be considered as standalone, then save in the model.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience you don't persist your changes until you save them so you can

- explicitly call `Model.save` in your controller
- explicitly call `Model.update_attributes(params[:model_attr])` in your controller
- if you want to save an attribute in your model I saw something like `write_attribute :attr_name, value` but TBH I never used it.

Cheers

Comment: I have tried calling save in the controller after post.unpublish() but that still does not work.