# Rails - Model changes not being saved or preserved between controller and model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, instance

I'd appreciate any help I can get with a somewhat strange phenonemon going on in my code. The controller's create method is (roughly) as follows:

```
def create
  @session ||= Session.new
  @session.date = params[:date]
  @session.generate_string
  @session.save
  # etc
end
```

And the model:

```
class Session < ActiveRecord::Base # table is 'sessions' with 3  columns :id, :str, :date
  include MyHelper

  def generate_string(num_chars)
    @str ||= ""

    num_chars.to_i.times do
      @str += some_method_in_MyHelper() # method returns a string
    end
  end
end
```

With some logging I found out that although the generate_string is working correctly, the resulting @session (in the controller) has the date set as expected but the value of str is a blank string. Sure enough, when the .save is hit, the database is told to insert a record consisting of a blank string and the correct date.

I found this [Why do my changes to model instances not get saved sometimes in Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848686/why-do-my-changes-to-model-instances-not-get-saved-sometimes-in-rails-3) that suggests I should be using the "self" prefix instead of @. This seems to make the code work as expected, but seems strange because I thought self.xxx referred to the class, not the class instance. I'd be grateful if anyone could clarify what's going on - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`self` refers to the instance when used inside an instance method. It refers to the class *outside* an instance method, when it (`self`) is the class that's being defined.

`@` is an instance variable, which is different than an `ActiveRecord` column.

Answer (score 0):

In order to store it in the `str` field to be saved to the database, you need to use `self.str` method. I think this is what you are looking for

```
class Session < ActiveRecord::Base # table is 'sessions' with 3  columns :id, :str, :date
  include MyHelper

  def generate_string(num_chars)
    str = ""

    num_chars.to_i.times do
      str += some_method_in_MyHelper() # method returns a string
    end

    self.str = str # store it in attribute to be saved into db
  end
end
```

Notice I removed the instance variable `@str` and changed it to local variable `str` instead because it seems like you want to generate a new string everytime this method is called? Also, this variable caching is useless

```
@session ||= Session.new
```

because instance variables only stick around for a single request. It should be

```
@session = Session.new
```

Comment: True, instance variables exist per-request, but without knowing what else happens before `create` is called, overwriting what might already be in @session isn't necessarily a good idea. It's not just an idiom for caching.